# Extended Events - How to capture executions for a given stored procedure along with the passed parameter values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, extended-events

How do you capture executions for a given stored procedure along with the passed parameter values?

I tried using sqlserver.module_end but it only shows the store proc execution with no param values:

```sql
CREATE EVENT SESSION [SP Executions By Name] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_end(SET collect_statement=(1)
ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.query_hash_signed,sqlserver.session_id,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([object_type]='P ' AND [sqlserver].[database_name]=N'MyDB' AND [object_name]=N'MyStoredProc'))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'Z:\Extended_Events\StoredProcedures_ByNameAndDB.xel',max_file_size=(5),max_rollover_files=(5))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
```

Comment: That methodology shows the execution of the sp but not the param values.  This sp is called from .NET code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible only if your proc is the oproc submitted in batch. If this is case, use rpc_completed or sql_batch_completed and filter with like predicate

Nested procs is notnpossible see parameters values.

Consider logging the parameters in a table for analsis.